# Arduino w/ TFT display - can't use PImage as an argument

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project that involves Arduino together with a TFT-display. I have created a class **tft** in cpp to initialize the tft display. I get an error when compiling saying "tft.h:18: error: 'PImage' has not been declared".
The line it's complaing about is (in h-file)

```
     uint8_t initScreen(TFT TFTscreen, PImage backgroundImage, uint8_t CS_SD, uint8_t CS_LD, uint8_t DC_LD, uint8_t RESET);
```

In the main program the PImage is declared as:

```
    TFT TFTscreen = TFT(CS_LD, DC_LD, RESET); 
    PImage backgroundImage;
```

In the tft class I have the following declarations:

```
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "tft.h"
    #include <TFT.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>

    tftclass::tftclass(){}

    uint8_t tftclass::initScreen(TFT TFTscreen, PImage backgroundImage, uint8_t CS_SD, uint8_t CS_LD, uint8_t DC_LD, uint8_t RESET)

    void tftclass::resetBackground(TFT TFTscreen, PImage backgroundImage)
```

The declaration in the header file is as following:

```
    #ifndef tft_h
    #define tft_h

    #include <TFT.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>

    class tftclass{

    public:
        tftclass();
        uint8_t initScreen(TFT TFTscreen, PImage backgroundImage, uint8_t CS_SD, uint8_t CS_LD, uint8_t DC_LD, uint8_t RESET);
        void resetBackground(TFT TFTscreen, PImage backgroundImage);
    };

    extern tftclass tft;

    #endif
```

Anyone having any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the filename from "tft.h" to "mytft.h", then report back..

Comment: I changed the names of the files but I now i get  a mulitple definitions error as you can see in here [link](http://pastebin.com/zSzm5zxp). I have tried to look for duplicates, but can't find any... Very strange.

Comment: you are lucky ;) yesterday I answered the exactly same question. Read the edit I made to [this answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22437/error-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-and-forward-declaration/22438#22438); the problem is the TFT library; apply the fixes I suggested and, hopefully, it'll work. Remember to apply that edits with the arduino ide closed, then open it when the modifications are done

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I get new errors saying that the SD-library is not found. You can check out the errors in the [link](http://pastebin.com/nnRsemYB) if you ought to.

Comment: In fact, it is giving you warnings and errors. You just have to read the output. The warnings are about the non-inclusion of `SD.h` before `Adafruit_GFX.h`. As written in the header file, `in order to use the image-related API of Adafruit_GFX, SD.h *must* be included before Adafruit_GFX`. This means that, in your `mytft.h` file, you have to include `SD.h` before `TFT.h`. And you also should include it in `Adafruit_GFX.cpp` file. Now, you have two paths. You can always include the SD library (and so you have to write `#include <SD.h>` before line 56 in `Adafruit_GFX.h`, or you can fix the cpp

Comment: files. To do this, in your `mytft.h` file include SD.h before TFT.h, then in `Adafruit_GFX.cpp` include SD.h at the beginning, before the other inclusions. And then you can either do the same for `TFT.cpp` and `Adafruit_ST7735.cpp` or you can ignore the warnings, it does not matter. But in the end you have an error, which blocks your compilation. It says "#include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>", which means that in file `PImage.cpp` there is `#include Adafruit_GFX.h` instead of `#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"` (it was a typo in the other answer, I fixed it)